# Order of the output doesn't match the order while running the function

Tags: r

I have a dataset with ID numbers and number of observations. I am writing a function to display output based on the IDs the user selects. The dataset have IDs starting from 1 to 332 and their corresponding observations.

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
complete=function(directory,id=1:332){
    directory=read.csv(paste(path,"complete.csv",sep=""),header=TRUE,sep=",")
    as.data.frame.matrix(directory)

    mydf=na.omit(directory)

    library(plyr)

    completecount=count(mydf$ID)
    colnames(completecount)=c("ID","nobs")
    as.data.frame.matrix(completecount)
    complete=subset(completecount,select=c(ID,nobs),subset=(completecount$ID%in%id))
    return(complete)
}
```

When I am trying to run this

```
complete("specdata",4:2)
```

I would like to see the output in the order below based on the input above

```
  ID nobs
2  4  474  
3  3  243
4  2 1041
```

Whereas I am seeing output in the order as shown below

```
  ID nobs
2  2 1041
3  3  243
4  4  474
```

Please advise what is wrong with my code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are these calls to `as.data.frame.matrix`? They don't seem to be doing anything as you are not saving the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your function that ensures any order. I'm not sure if you think the `%in%` operator also does sorting but it does not. It returns values no matter the order the second parameter is in. The order you are returning the rows is the order they were in in the original table.

Unlike `%in%`, `match()` actually does return values in order. You could do something like

```
library(plyr)

complete=function(directory,id=1:332){
    directory=read.csv(paste(path,"complete.csv",sep=""),header=TRUE,sep=",")
    as.data.frame.matrix(directory)

    mydf=na.omit(directory)

    completecount=count(mydf$ID)
    colnames(completecount)=c("ID","nobs")
    as.data.frame.matrix(completecount)
    return(completecount[match(id, completecount$ID), ])
}
```

This will pluck rows out of `completecount` in the order they they are passed to the function.